# Axon extensions.mongo 4.3 in spring boot: noSuchMethodError - com.mongodb.MongoClient

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, axon-framework

i'm trying to run `mvn clean install` on a spring boot project with Axon's `extensions.mongo` dependency. The mongo database is up and running in a docker container

in the pom i have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework.extensions.mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then i have a @Configuration class which has - among others, these members:

```
 @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host:127.0.0.1}")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int mongoPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database:user}")
    private String mongoDatabase;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        var mongoFactory = new MongoFactory();
        mongoFactory.setMongoAddresses(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort)));

        return mongoFactory.createMongo();
    }
```

Then when running `mvn clean install` i get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClient' defined in com.springbank.user.core.configuration.AxonConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)'
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)'
```

Comment: You are using an incompatible version. Also the `mongoclient` would already be available through the autoconfiguration so isn't needed.

Comment: thanks for the input; i saw in another question that this might be the case - but what is the compatible version in this case? I mean is there a version i could use so that this configuration is applied? I tried others - down to 4.1 but nothing seems to work

Comment: 4.1 of what? This simply looks like you are using a Mongo Driver that is incompatible with the Spring Mongo version you are using. As you are using Spring Boot this probably means you are messing around with versions too much.

Comment: i was referring to the org.axonframework.extensions.mongo dependency; i tried with 4.3, went to other versions as well (including that 4.1); i assumed that's what you meant by saying incompatible version - the mongo extension. So basically i tried changing the version of the mongo driver, then retried `mvn clean install`

Comment: As mentioned the `MongoFactory` (whatever is delivering that class), is expecting a newer/older version of the MonogDB version that you are currently using. IMHO you shouldn't need that method and Spring Boot will automatically configure the `MongoClient` for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, removing the config helped build the app; i can't mark the last answer as approved but maybe someone else can

Comment: It is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot will auto-configure the `MongoClient` when it is available on the classpath. You only need to specify the proper `spring.mongo` properties in your `application.properties` (which you already use judging by your configuration).

So the easy fix is to just remove this `@Bean` method.

If you really want to use that `MongoFactory` you will need to figure out which version of MongoDB (the Mongo Client in this case) is compatible with it.